# React integration with cucumberjs

Tags: reactjs, webpack, cucumber, enzyme, next.js

I am working on a React-Nextjs project and trying to integrate the BDD tool [cucumber](https://cucumber.io/docs/reference/javascript) for specification and feature level testing. Though am having some trouble integrating `cucumber` with React when using `enzyme` to shallow render the component:

Here's the errors am getting: 
`TypeError: Cannot read property 'contextTypes' of undefined` at `const wrapper = shallow(<Referrer/>);`

Code for cucumber step test file:

```
import React from 'react';
import { defineSupportCode } from "cucumber";
import { shallow } from "enzyme";
import {Referrer} from "./../../components/Referrer";

defineSupportCode(({ Given, When, Then }) => {
    Given("I want to do something", function (callback) {
        // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
        callback();
    });

    When("Xyz link is clicked", function (callback) {
        const wrapper = shallow(<Referrer/>);
        ... // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
    });

    Then("Appropriate action happens", function (callback) {
        // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
        callback();
    });
});
```

The component is a simple UI component, pretty straight forward, here's its structure:

```
import React from "react"; // eslint-disable-line no-unused-vars

export default class Referrer extends React.Component {
    render () {
        return (
            <div className="some-class" id="some-id">
              // html tags
              <style jsx>{`
                .some-class {
                  //styling
                }

                .some-class2 {
                  //styling
                }
              `}
              </style>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

I am using `"cucumber": "^2.3.1"`, `"enzyme": "^2.6.0"`, I am not sure how to resolve this, no help so far online, I have been trying to debug for last couple hours but no luck.

Exact error snippet:

```
Warning: React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in.
```

`TypeError: Cannot read property 'contextTypes' of undefined` at `const wrapper = shallow(<Referrer/>);`

Comment: Do you have any babel preset to make it working?

Comment: I didnt need any, the issue was how I was importing the component.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I realized what was wrong, my `Referrer` component is being exported as a default, though I wasn't importing it correctly. I had to import it as `import Referrer from "./../../components/Referrer";` instead of `import {Referrer} from "./../../components/Referrer";`